# Can it be possible to go back to the "What topics can I ask about here?" article after viewing the history?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, help-center

When editing a normal post, you can see the revision history and then go back via a link in the upper-left-hand corner.

I just edited the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page on Mythology as a moderator, then viewed the history. I realized that I could not go back to the page, as usual!

I checked the same thing on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and found the same issue.

Here is a screenshot of the history page, showing where the link on a normal post's history is:

[image]

Can a link please be added?